# To pre-slice or not to pre-slice fajitas?

Tags: marinade, mexican-cuisine

In both skirt and flank steak, and when cooking indoor, is it more ideal to preslice marinate then cook? or marinate cook then slice?

My understanding is that pre-slicing allows you to marinate more, but at the price of meat juice.

Comment: If you are cooking in a skillet I don't see that you have choice

Comment: I actually use this indoor panin/grill device, which suggests it goes up to 450 degrees, and has plenty of space [indoor grill](http://www.williams-sonoma.com/products/1640184/?catalogId=27&sku=1640184&cm_ven=Google_PLA&cm_cat=Shopping&cm_pla=default&cm_ite=default&kwid=productads-adid^52929360103-device^c-plaid^102592298743-sku^1640184-adType^PLA&gclid=CjwKEAjw19vABRCY2YmkpO2OzTsSJAAzEt8sO9Odc962caGE3CbKYWiPL-KQqRmsTxzxW3W7jZY-ChoCX2Dw_wcB)

Comment: Then maybe try both ways and see what you prefer.  This is going to personal preference.

Answer (score 1):

Marinating only works on the surface of the meat as salt is the only thing that can get inside the slice of meat. So I suggest marinating the meat sliced and then cooking it. Extra bonus - cooking time is shorter!

I have some extra tips, take if you want. A good idea is to cook it hot and quickly like in a wok, but if you don't have a wok then that's okay (I don't have one myself). That way you sear the outside of the slices and what juice there is in the small piece of meat should stay in. If you do cook at high heat remember to use an oil with a high smoking point, like avocado, ghee, lard, or coconut oil.

Comment: Generally good advice, but note that searing doesn't actually seal in juices. Slicing the meat will allow you to develop better flavor on more seared surfaces, though.  And the marinade will be more effective and will be absorbed a bit more into the meat (with more surface area), thereby somewhat offsetting the moisture loss during cooking.

Comment: I guess maybe I was thinking of velveted meats.

Comment: If the focus is time, the cooking might be quicker, but it increases the prep time.  I save a little bit of time in the cooking by cooking the meat first (unsliced) while I prep the vegetables.  Then let it rest for a few minutes while cooking the vegetables; once the vegetables have a little char on the first side, flip them, and slice the meat.  (and you can use the same knife from slicing veg).  And when cooking at my neighbor's house, we use a similar countertop press (that opens up to become a flat grill; we use the griddle inserts for this)